# simplify the expression $\arctan\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Same as above, how to simplify it. I am to calculate its $n$th derivative w.r.t x where t is const, but I can't simplify it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is $\tan^{-1}x$ equal to $\frac{1}{\tan x}$ or to $\arctan x$?

Comment: Its inverse of tangent fn (arctanx)

Comment: @Shobhit, Is $t$ independent of $x$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes t is const x is var

Comment: @labbhattacharjee any ideas??

Comment: @Shobhit, I will share only when I've something elegant

Comment: @labbhattacharjee affirmative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good question, especially one artificially contrived, should teach us some lesson. i think in this case the lesson is that it is important to know *when* to apply simplification.

in the case of the given example we have 
$$
f(x) = \frac{ x \sin t}{1 - x\cos t} \\
y = \arctan f(x)
$$
using ' to indicate differentiation w.r.t $x$, and also the abbreviations $s$ and $c$ for $\sin t$ and $\cos t$  we notice the first derivative allows some simplification:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{s (1-x c) - x s (-c)}{(1-x c)^2} = \frac{s}{(1-xc)^2} 
$$
and 
$$y' = \frac{f'(x)}{1 + f(x)^2}
$$
where
$$
1 + f(x)^2 = 1 + \frac{x^2 s^2 }{(1-xc)^2} = \frac{x^2-2xc+1}{(1 -xc)^2}
$$
so, altogether:
$$ y' = \frac{s}{x^2-2xc+1}
$$
since the denominator factors as $(x-e^{it})(x-e^{-it})$ this first derivative, expressed in partial fractions, is now easy to use as a basis for iteration. i.e. we have (something like)
$$
y' = \frac{i}2 \left((x-e^{-it})^{-1} - (x-e^{it})^{-1} \right)
$$

Comment: Great idea, but I think you solved it wrong, mind checking 1+f^2

Comment: And the answer on correction does not help.

Comment: yes, wishful thinking often leads me astray! thanks for checking! i will delete the "answer|"

Comment: maybe the basic idea was ok. i had the complex factorization originally, but as already mentioned, got led astray in the "simplification". hope this isn't another egregious error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Maybe:}$
If you are looking to take the nth derivtive with respect to x then I would re-write as
$$
\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t} = \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\ln(u)
$$
and then take the n-th derivtive as
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f\left[\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}\right]= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f\left[\frac{d}{dt}\ln(u)\right]
$$
$\textbf{edit/coming clean}$
I totally misread and forgot to include the arctan so I have included an arbitrary function f. I think it might still be easier to approach from this way. :)

Comment: Sorry forget to mension, it has to be wrt x :(

Comment: To be honest I completely forgot the $\arctan$ bit so we are even ha.

Comment: True :D so any idea????

Comment: Does not help, or I can't see how. You just replaced.elaborate

Comment: Basically the approach I was taking was to reduce the argument for $\arctan$ to a simple derivative ie a simpler function to take the nth derivative of  with respect to x. I am not saying that this is the best approach, but it is the approach that make sense since the numerator is just the derivative of the denominator. Does that make sense?

Comment: But seeing as in your updated question that $t$ is const, then there is most likely an easier way forward.

Comment: Derivative of denom. Are u sure???????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16027/discussion-between-chinny84-and-shobhit).

Comment: @Shobit thx. i deleted the "answer" - unfortunately this deleted your comment pointing out my mistake, and my acknowledgement. led astray by wishful thinking!

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity of deriving the formula, I'll assume $x$ is small and real.
One can "analytic continue" the formula once we get it.

Let $\theta(x)$ be the function $\displaystyle\;\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sin t}{1 - x\cos t}\right)\;$. For small and real $x$, we can rewrite $\theta(x)$ as

$$\theta(x) = \Im\log\left(1 + i\frac{x\sin t}{1 - x\cos t}\right)
= \Im\log(1 - xe^{-it})
$$
Let $z = xe^{-it}$. For $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, we have

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\theta(x)
= \Im\left[e^{-int}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\log(1 - z)\right]
= -\Im\left[e^{-int}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-z)^n}\right]
$$
Notice
$$1 - z = (1- x\cos t)\left(1 + i\frac{x\sin t}{1 - x\cos t}\right) 
= \sqrt{1 - 2x\cos t + x^2} e^{i\theta}
$$
This leads to
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sin t}{1 - x\cos t}\right)
= (n-1)!\frac{\sin n\left[t + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sin t}{1 - x\cos t}\right)\right]}{( 1 - 2x\cos t + x^2)^{n/2}}$$
For example, when  $n = 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\theta'(x) 
&= \frac{\sin(t+\theta)}{\sqrt{1-2x\cos t + x^2}}
 = \frac{\sin t + \cos t \tan\theta}{\sqrt{1-2x\cos t + x^2}}\cos\theta\\
&= \frac{\sin t + \cos t\frac{x \sin t}{1-x\cos t}}{\sqrt{1-2x\cos t + x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}\right)^2}}
 = \frac{\sin t(1 - x\cos t) + x \sin t\cos t}{\sqrt{1 - 2x\cos t + x^2}^2}\\
&= \frac{\sin t}{1 - 2x\cos t + x^2}\\
\end{align}
$$
The same answer you get if you differentiate $\theta(x)$ directly.

Comment: What is that symbol before log

Comment: @Shobhit That symbol $\Im$ stands for taking imaginary part (this is standard on M.SE).

Comment: Under the argument of log,  1+ixsint/(...)  =  1-xe^(it), when I expand these they are not same. Help.

Comment: @Shobhit $$\begin{align}\log(1-x e^{-it}) &= \log\left((1-x\cos t)\left(1 + i\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}\right)\right)\\ &= \log(1-x\cos t)+\log\left(1 + i\frac{x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}\right)\end{align}$$ and $\log(1-x\cos t)$ is real!